# can i move UITextView on my touch events ? or i can recognize touch on UITextView?

Tags: iphone, ios4

hey friend in my View their is one textview(For que.) by tapping on that i have to filp new view(for answer) but textView not recognize touch event....

Please help me

thanks in advancce

Answer (score 1):

Subclass the UITextView and override `becomeFirstResponder:`.
This will fire if the text view's keyboard comes up, which will happen if you touch it (unless you set first responder programatically; you'll have to handle that).

Comment: That would have been a valuable information in the question!
Then override UITextView and implement touchesBegan:, touchesEnded: and whatever else you need.